# How is the partition function related to Stirling numbers of second kind

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, combinations

If S(n,k) finds the number of partitions of n in k parts. And p(n) is the number of partitions of n, then does p(n) equals a summation of S(n,k) for all possible k. If not why? And are they related at all?

Comment: The Stirling numbers count partitions of  a set of distinguishable objects. So $\sum_k S(n,k)$ is the $n$-th Bell number.

Comment: [Partition numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) on the other hand count the number of ways of partitioning sets of *indistinguishable* objects.

Comment: There is something called the [Twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#Formulas) it relates some combinatorial formulas and put them nicely in a table where you can find both partitions and Stirling numbers hopefully the difference can made be clearer looking at it

Comment: @dandide why does it mention "any f". It should be bijective, right?

Comment: @MathLearner  it it should be (any, injective, surjective, bijective) as possibilities but the bijective case is not in the added because it means that the cardinalities have to be the same so all you have to do is take any element in the injective or surjective column and use $n=x$ so for example taking the binomial from the injective table ${x  \choose n}$ you get that the bijective case is ${n \choose n}$ and the same happen if you choose a formula from the surjective column so they always coincide for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each integer partition of $n$ into $k$ parts corresponds to one *or more* set partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts. The proportion depends on the integer partition. For example, $3, 2, 1, 1 \vdash 7$ corresponds to $\binom{7}{3} \binom{4}{2} \binom{2}{1} \binom{1}{1} \frac{1}{1! 1! 2!}$ set partitions, where the final adjustment accounts for the fact that subsets of the same size chosen in different orders would otherwise be overcounted.

The fact that the proportion is different for each integer partition means that there won't be a simple relationship between $S(n, k)$ and $p(n)$,unless you count $\sum_k S(n, k) \ge p(n)$.